# ExpressJs not protecting/skipping protected file

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, cookies

I've created a simple authentication system. The user submits a user name, the route checks the user exist in the database, and if so a signed cookies is assigned to the user for access to all other routes. This system works for protecting all other routes; however, there seems to be a problem with protecting the final angular route that servers the index file.

Prior to the `app.use()` which serves the angular file , I placed a middleware which redirects to the login page if there is no user cookie. The problem is if you go to localhost:3000 without the proper user cookie you are sent right through to the angular app, but the protection on the api routes are in place and will be blocked. If you go to localhost:3000/randomwords without the cookie , you are sent to the user login page. There seems to be something in my applications flow that I'm missing.

So how do I properly protect the angular route, so that a user without a cookie is always sent to the auth page and can login from there.

Also I've even deleted the angular route, saved and restarted the app and it still serves the angular app. How is that possible??!

Login submit post request

```
module.exports.submitLoginForm = function(req,res, next){

    let foundUser = User.findOne({'userName': userName});

    foundUser
        .then(user=>{

        if(tester){
            res.cookie('user', user._id, {signed: true})
            res.redirect('/');
        }
            res.redirect('/auth/');
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
   });
}
```

app.js

```
//how all other routes are protect in app.js (This works!)

authMiddleWare = function(req,res,next){
    if (req.signedCookies['user']) {
        next();

    } else {
       sendJSONresponse(res, 400, {err:"error"})
   }
}

app.use('/api/info', authMiddleWare,infoApi);


//middleware and angular route

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.signedCookies['user']) {
       next()

    } else {
       res.redirect('/auth/');
    }

});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone that might come across this issue. Farther above in the app.js file  I used the standard

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

to serve static files. For some reason this causes express to serve the index.html file for the Angular app no matter what. I moved it down below the auth middleware and now it works!

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.session.user) {
        next()

    } else {
        res.redirect('/auth/');
    }

});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public/dist')));

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public/dist', 'index.html'));
});
```